# "ISO-8859-1" Encoding in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, base64, iso-8859-1, iconv

I've created a base64 encoding `string` in the following format using C#. I want to create the same encoded string using JavaScript.

```
var isoEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
var a = isoEncoding.GetBytes(username + ":" + password);
String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(a);
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
```

Here I used `iconv` and try to get encoded `string` and it gives a differen encoded string. what can be the reason?

```
var str  = this.username+':'+this.password;
var s = iconv.encode(str, 'ISO-8859-1');
var a = btoa(s.toString()); 
headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + a);
```

Comment: `it does not work.` Define 'does not work'.

Comment: Have you tried `s` instead of `s.toString()`?

Comment: @mjwills, sorry i edited. It gives a different encode string.

Comment: @Ruud yes,but btoa need string to encode.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `btoa`:

```
var a = s.toString('base64');
```

The default encoding for `buffer.toString` is utf-8

Comment: This gives same as btoa. Issue is encoded string is different for the c# one.